# passing transactions with REQUIRES_NEW propagination from one function to another

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I have problem with @Transactional annotation i am not able to solve.
I understand that with Propagation.REQUIRED existing transaction is used or created new one if there is no transaction active.
And that with Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW new transaction is created and should be commited before returning to other existing transactions.

I want to achieve the following:

when i am looping through list of tasks
if any error happens while in completeTaskOrDoSomethingElse function 
revert all transactions that happened in that function, dont revert transactions for other tasks in list of tasks.

if error happens in completeTask() function revert transactions from that function 
if error happens in sendTaskAfterInsertToOtherService() revert transactions that happened in sendTaskAfterInsertToOtherService() and in completeTask() functions

not sure how to do it because task has to be commited in order to get data from database, and as far as i know if transaction is commited it cant be reverted.

Any help is appreciated, i will provide any aditional information

```
     mainFunction()
  {
    for(task in listOfTasks)
        completeTaskOrDoSomethingElse(task);
  }
  
  @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  completeTaskOrDoSomethingElse(Task task)
  {
     Task newTask= completetask(task);
    
     sendTaskAfterInsertToOtherService(task.getId());

   //if error happens in sendTaskAfterInsertToOtherService() revert data from both 
//sendTaskAfterInsertToOtherService() and completetask() functions

  
  }
  
  @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  completeTask()
  {
    //insert task into db
  }
  
    //if completeTask() doesnt have REQUIRES_NEW propagination transaction wont be commited to db and when i try to get task by id exception happens because 
    task is not saved to db
 sendTaskAfterInsertToOtherService(task.getId())
     {
        task = taskDao.getById()
        
        //insert to db
        callOtherService(task);
     
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

When using Spring Transaction, even if the REQUIRES_NEW propagation property is used, it rolls back to the parent transaction because the same transaction manager is set up.

There are two ways to implement the scenario you want.

1. Catch exception from transaction method and handle

- If you want that parent transaction is not reverted when child transaction reverted, you can catch exception of method with child transaction and handle it.

2. using `TransactionEventListener`

- completeTaskOrDoSomethingElse(task); publish an event at the place of call, sendTaskAfterInserToOtherService(task.getId()) publish an event at the place of call.
- Implementing an EventListner that performs the tasks you want to do in the child transaction. If implemented through the `AFTER_COMIT` property, the parent transaction is not affected when the child transaction is rolled back.

  - ref) [TransactionalEventListener Of Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html)

Comment: You can perfectly use new transactions with a single tx manager, you jnust need to make sure you are properly catching them. What you state here is totally wrong.

Comment: @M.Deinum 
First of all, if I'm misunderstanding, I'd like to apologize for the wrong answer. My intention was not to mean that a new transaction could not be used, but that if you operate with a new transaction but generally use transaction propagation within the same thread, it could even roll back to the parent transaction.
In addition to the answers I left behind, could you please let me know how I can solve it through a single transaction manager? :)

Comment: Your answer is still incorrect. You don't need additional transaction managers, that might even make things worse. If you use new transactions, you need to handle errors, if you let them propagate it will rollback the parent. However adding an additional tx manager won't resolve that it will rollback as well. The `TransactionEventLIstener` won't work either as there will be just 1 commit not mulitple.

Comment: @M.Deinum
Thank you for giving me feedback. I've edited my answer.
but I don't understand yet that 'The TransactionEventLIstener won't work either as there will be just 1 commit not mulitple.'. I'll study more about it.